# Display-flex; Flex-direction column

Tags: css, flexbox

on Click function I am creating a parent div with Javascript, I set for it display-flex, flex direction column. but second child div that is put in this parent div doesn't act as flex-direction column, because it goes to the top left not below the first div.

```js
const createLogin2 = () => {
    const line1 = document.createElement("div");
    line1.classList.add("line1");

    const line2 = document.createElement("div");
    line2.classList.add("line2");
    let image = document.createElement("img");
    image.src = "./twitch/download.png";
    image.classList.add("imagestyle");
    line2.appendChild(image);

    const line3 = document.createElement("div");
    line3.classList.add("line3");
    const linelabel = document.createElement("h3");
    linelabel.innerText = "Login in to Twitch";
    line3.appendChild(linelabel);
    line1.appendChild(line2);
    line1.appendChild(line3);
    return line1;
  };

  const login1 = createFirstLoginDiv();
  const login2 = createLogin2();

  login1.appendChild(login2);
  login.appendChild(login1);

  const createLogin3 = () => {
    const line4 = document.createElement("div");
    line4.classList.add("line4");
    return line4;
  };

  const line5 = createLogin3();
  login1.appendChild(line5);
```

```css
.loginfirst {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; 
  z-index: 1;
}

.line1 {
  top: 5%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
}

.line2 {
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-top: 5%;
}

.imagestyle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.line3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.line4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #772ce8;
```

```html
<div class="login">
  <div class="movelogin" id="createlogin" onclick="logIn()">
    <button class="login1">
      <div class="Login1">Log In</div>
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I am changing positions, also changing z-index, I am pretty sure that this second div should go below. of the first div but I don't understand what is happening

Comment: I used justify-content: center and align-items: center and fixed the issue.

Comment: You should create an answer with this.

Answer (score 0):

I used justify-content: center and align-items: center and fixed the issue.